# Install fails for dBASE III Administrator, "goto was unexpected"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos, dbase, ntvdm

I am a novice programmer/IT guy at my family owned real estate finance business. Long story short, we created a dBASE III based application system to track all customer accounts about 25-30 years ago. The cost to change to a modern system would be astronomical and since I can code with some reasonable efficiency we keep it. It does all right, but everyone is using a single user version on separate workstations. I want to install dBASE administrator and change things over to a networked environment. I figured going into it I would be a little out of my depth but would be able to work through it. I am currently running this on a Windows XP system, no internet connection, all simply LANd together.

I got the install disk image from vetusware. I mounted the image via Virtual Floppy. In the command prompt I navigate to the disk and follow the instructions from the manual:

> 2. Insert System Disk #1 in drive A.
> 3. Change the default drive to A by typing A:[return]

So far so good...I have an A prompt.

> Then type:
>   A> INSTALL C: DBA

I type the "INSTALL C: DBA", it launched the "INSTALL.BAT" found on the disk, but quickly reports back "goto was unexpected at this time." and returns me to the A prompt.

I will post the batch file text below. Upon execution it displays the top bit of "echoed" text finishing with "...previous version of dBASE." But then the next line is the "goto was unexpected..."

It seems like this is something wrong with the INSTALL batch file and nothing that I am doing... I know that that is a batch file error and not an error from within the program. Also odd, the program mentions this DBA.COM and it is nowhere to be found on any of the disks... Any help or guidance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

Chris

```
    echo off
    cls
    echo 
    echo                dBASE III PLUS VERSION 1.1
    echo                  HARD DISK INSTALLATION 
    echo 
    echo You can copy  dBASE III PLUS  to your  hard disk  by following
    echo these  installation  instructions.  You  can  also  use  these
    echo instructions to install dBASE ADMINISTRATOR.
    echo 
    echo If you want to  save a  previously installed version of dBASE,
    echo uninstall it using that version's UNINSTAL program.
    echo 
    echo If you choose not  to save a  previous version,  install dBASE
    echo III PLUS Version 1.1 into the same directory.  This will auto-
    echo matically erase the previous version of dBASE.
    echo 
    if "%1==" goto Helpinst
    for %%f in (C:,c:,D:,d:,E:,e:,F:,f:,G:,g:,H:,h:,Y:,y:) do if %1.==%%f. goto START
    for %%f in (I:,i:,J:,j:,K:,k:,L:,l:,M:,m:,N:,n:,O:,o:,P:,p:,Z:,z:) do if %1.==%%f. goto START
    for %%f in (Q:,q:,R:,r:,S:,s:,T:,t:,U:,u:,V:,v:,W:,w:,X:,x:) do if %1.==%%f. goto START
    goto BADDRIVE
    :START
    if "==%2" goto DBASE
    if %2.==DBA. goto DBA
    if %2.==dba. goto DBA
    goto Helpinst
    :DBASE
    echo dBASE III PLUS will be installed on drive %1
    echo 
    yn Y N 30 Do you want to continue (Y/N)?
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto DBASE1
    goto END
    :DBASE1
    if exist dbase.lod goto ID
    if exist %1dbase.exe goto ErrExist
    if exist %1dba.com goto ERREXT
    if not exist id.exe goto MISS
    %1
    a:id /S
    a:
    echo Copying files to drive %1 . . .
    echo 
    copy dbase.exe %1
    copy dbaseinl.ovl %1
    copy dbase.msg %1
    if not exist %1config.db copy config.db %1
    if not exist %1config.sys copy config.sys %1
    :SYS2
    echo 
    echo Insert the dBASE III PLUS System Disk #2 in drive A.
    echo 
    pause
    if not exist dbase.ovl goto SYS2
    echo 
    echo Copying files to drive %1 . . .
    echo 
    copy dbase.ovl %1
    copy help.dbs %1
    copy assist.hlp %1
    if not exist %1dbase.ovl goto ErrDbase
    if not exist %1dbase.exe goto ErrDbase
    if not exist %1dbase.msg goto ErrDbase
    if not exist %1dbaseinl.ovl goto ErrDbase
    echo 
    echo dBASE III PLUS has been successfully installed.
    goto End
    :DBA
    echo dBASE ADMINISTRATOR will be installed on drive %1
    echo 
    yn Y N 30 Do you want to continue (Y/N)?
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Ad1
    goto END
    :Ad1
    if exist dba.lod goto GETSYS1
    if exist %1dba.com goto ERREXT
    if exist %1dbase.exe goto ErrExist
    if not exist dbaseinl.ovl goto GETSYS1
    echo 
    echo Copying files to drive %1 . . .
    echo 
    copy help.dbs %1
    echo 
    :AD2
    echo 
    echo Insert the Administrator #1 disk in drive A
    echo 
    pause
    echo 
    if not exist dba.lod goto AD2
    :AD3
    if exist installh.sg3 goto INITDBA
    if not exist idlan.exe goto MISS
    %1
    a:idlan /M
    a:
    installh p=a t=%1
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ErrDBA
    echo 
    copy dba.lod %1\dbnetctl.300
    copy dbase.msg %1
    copy protect.exe %1
    copy assist.hlp %1
    echo 
    :Ad4
    echo 
    echo Insert the Administrator #2 disk in drive A
    echo 
    pause
    echo 
    if not exist dba.ovl goto AD4
    echo Copying files to drive %1 . . .
    echo 
    copy dba.ovl %1
    copy adduser.com %1
    echo 
    echo dBASE ADMINISTRATOR has been successfully installed
    echo  
    echo One user may now run dBASE ADMINISTRATOR.  To add more users,
    echo run the  ADDUSER program.  The ADDUSER  program is located in
    echo the directory in which dBASE ADMINISTRATOR is installed.
    echo 
    goto END
    :Helpinst
    echo  You entered the command incorrectly.  The correct syntax is:
    echo 
    echo    "INSTALL <drive:>"      To install dBASE III PLUS.
    echo 
    echo    "INSTALL <drive:> DBA"      To install dBASE ADMINISTRATOR.
    echo 
    echo Install is aborted.
    goto End
   :ErrExist
    echo 
    echo  dBASE III PLUS already exists in the destination drive.
    goto ErrUnst
   :ERREXT
    echo 
    echo  dBASE ADMINISTRATOR already exists in the destination drive.
    :ErrUnst
    echo 
    echo Install is aborted.
    goto End
    :BADDRIVE
    echo  
    echo Invalid drive letter specified.  Install is aborted.
    goto Helpinst
    :ErrDbase
    echo  
    echo dBASE III PLUS is not installed.  Install is aborted.
    goto END
    :MISS
    echo  
    echo Your system disk has missing files.  Install is aborted.
    echo 
    goto DELFILE
    :ID
    echo  
    echo dBASE III PLUS has not been identified.  Please run ID.
    echo 
    goto END
    :INITDBA
    echo  
    echo dBASE ADMINISTRATOR has not been identified.  Please run IDLAN.
    echo 
    goto DELFILE
    :GETSYS1
    echo  
    echo Please use the dBASE III PLUS System Disk #1 to run the installation.
    echo Install is aborted.
    echo 
    goto END
    :ErrDBA
    echo  
    echo dBASE ADMINISTRATOR installation has been aborted.
    echo 
    :DELFILE
    if exist %1help.dbs del %1help.dbs
    :End
```

Comment: 1. Read this help topic before asking questions in future: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2. Remove `echo off` for debugging! 3. For case-**in**sensitive comparisons, use `if /I`. 4. There is no native `yn` command, so is it an external tool? otherwise check out the `choice` command.

Comment: Try entering `command` and then following the instructions.

Comment: @aschipfl YN.EXE is(was?) an external program that was part of DBase III+

Comment: You could run the batch file from within command prompt window with first line changed to `echo on` to see on which line the batch file fails. `if "==%2" goto DBASE` is definitely not correct. I suppose this line should be `if ""=="%~2" goto DBASE`, i.e. check if there is no second argument passed to the batch file on calling it and in this case continue on label `DBASE`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, sorry I violated a few customs. Debugging it I ended up REMing out a few lines one of which @Mofi mentioned and was able to proceed through the installation. I am now much further along but have hit another snag. I mentioned before I can't seem to locate this DBA.COM file, and it is giving me an error because of it when trying to run the Adduser program. I will soldier on and see if I can't locate where that file is supposed to be... or how to get it...

Thanks again!

Comment: It appears the DBA.COM file is supposed to be created by the `INSTALLH` program. Either your changes to the install script broke the script or you've run afoul of the application's copy protection and/or licence management scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the install script was written for the MS-DOS command interpreter (`COMMAND.COM`) and isn't compatible with the Windows XP command interpreter (`cmd.exe`). The specific problem is that the XP interpreter gives special meaning to double quote characters (") while the MS-DOS interpreter doesn't. This causes the following line to be interpreted differently, as an error, under XP:

```
if "%1==" goto Helpinst
```

I don't recommend trying to "fix" the script to be Windows XP compatible. Aside from the fact that there a number of lines like this you would have to fix, there's a much simpler solution. Just use the MS-DOS command interpreter. You can do this by entering `command` at the command prompt. Then just follow the instructions as normal. For example:

```
command 
a:
install c: dba
```